# Debian-Jessie: How do you check iptables status?

Tags: debian, iptables, systemd, firewall

In old sysvinit I would just do `service iptables status` and see if it was running or not.

But in newer Debian-Jessie I grep for iptables in the list of services and don't see iptables listed anywhere. And when I try to query the status via systemctl status iptables I get an error.

Debian-Jessie: How do you check iptables status?

Answer (score 9):

Iptables in Linux is implemented as a number of kernel modules. Normally it is configured by some init script - but you can add and remove rules on the fly from the command line. So basically, there are (at least) thee relevant questions:

- Are the kernel modules loaded?
- Are any rules applied?
- Is my firewall script/program "running"?

The old iptables "service" was obsoleted by systemd. I think [this project](https://github.com/gronke/systemd-iptables) attempts to make a similar "service" available for Debian.

To see if the kernel modules are loaded:

```
# lsmod | grep ip_tables
```

To see the effective rules:

```
# iptables -L
```

or, if you want to see the NAT rules:

```
# iptables -t nat -L
```

In Debian there are a number of firewall packages that can set up the iptables rules for you. (I have not tried any of them, I usually roll out my own when I need it).

```
apt-cache search firewall | grep firewall | less
```

Comment: Under Fedora 20/21 with systemd when I list the services `systemctl list-unit-files --type=service`, I still see `iptables` and `firewalld` --> compared to Debian-Jessie when I run the same command I don't see any `iptables` or `firewalld`. NOT seeing `iptables` or some sort of firewall service is what confuses me.

Comment: is there command to run that that says yes/no, true/false, stopped/running, enabled/disabled?